Pega - Accessing condition and property values from decisiontable
I am aware of the export function in the GUI to export the decisiontable. Problem however that I am facing at the moment is that we want to share the conditions and the result to an external system.
We created a 4 property dropdown menu that we interlock with the decision table. (so only valid combinations can be chosen)
With the lowest property all preceding conditions are available in the decision table. When I trace the OOTB export function I see it is entering an activity and one of the first steps is a Page-Copy, in this Page-Copy step a dataPage RH_1 is shown. In this datapage all in this datapage, all info that I need to export is available. in pyColumns(2-4).pyCondition(1-319) and the results in pyPropertyColumns(1).pyPropertyValue(1-319)
Until now we just manually exported the lowest level decisiontable and send it to the other team by email. But they want to automate this procedure so for example the data is obtained biweekly and send to the other teams system without any human intervention.
Also the format of the 'normal' exported has to be adapted for the other system and preferably JSON is received in stead of excel format.
How can I configure a Page-Copy so I can access the decision table properties for further processing?
Does anyone else have maybe a better solution?
I have looked into obj-browse and obtainValue without success, but maybe looking in the wrong direction

Just open that Decision Table and look at the RH_1 page on the clipboard for the Decision Table name Thread , then you will see two imp pages on expanding RH_1, pyColumns and pyResults.
pyColumns gives the the columns and their repeating rows values .
pyResults gives the final returned column values.
Now if you do Obj-Open-By-Handle in an Activity for that Decision Table using its pzInsKey, then you can form a desired clipboard page from the pyColumns and pyResults pages.
Now you got the desired output clipbaord Page. You can convert that Page in JSON string and pass it to your client through an automated mail (Job schedule) or through a Rest connector.
